# Is it possible to write an if statement with a word instead of a number as an input in Python

Tags: python

So I'm new to Python and I'm trying to write a simple if statement that looks similar to this:

```
pizza = input("Does pineapple belong on pizza? ")
if pizza == yes:
print('good')
```

However when I run it I get a error message that looks like this:

```
pizza = input("Does pineapple belong on pizza? ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
```

How can I fix this? It works fine if the script is something like;

```
if pizza == 3:
      print(good)
```

Comment: Dammit I formatted the code wrong sorry

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a tutorial resource.  Just keep working through the learning materials.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose yes in inverted commas:

```
if pizza == "yes":
    print("good")
```

Explanation

`yes` : variable

`"yes"` : string

When you type `if pizza == yes`, interpreter check value of variable `pizza` and compare it with value of variable `yes`. But there is no variable named `yes` defined. So you get the error.

But when you do `if pizza == "yes"`, if compare value of `pizza` directly with string `"yes"`. That's what you want to do.

Comment: if this solve you problem correctly, click the tick button to accept it as answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat the response as text by putting it in quotes.

```
pizza = input("Does pineapple belong on pizza? [Y/N]: ")
if pizza == 'Y':
    print('Correct, but only when combined with ham.')
```